# tomee-maven-plugin

Tags: java-ee, tomee

Для чего нужен этот плагин и будет ли он работать на боевом проекте? Потому что без него выходит следующая ошибка:

```
12-Jan-2019 12:32:08.441 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false]
12-Jan-2019 12:32:08.468 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: F:\Developer\Programms\Chessman\ChessmanWork\target\ChessmanWork
12-Jan-2019 12:32:08.874 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ChessmanWork] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
12-Jan-2019 12:32:08.876 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ChessmanWork] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:70)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12-Jan-2019 12:32:09.218 INFO [48] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1006)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Вот сам плагин

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <tomeeClassifier>plume</tomeeClassifier>
                  <args>-Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m</args>
                  <libs>
                    <lib>mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13</lib>
                  </libs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Вот его описание: https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-maven-plugin.html. Я подозреваю, что интересовало что-то конкретное, но тогда это надо уточнить в своем вопросе.

Comment: @demas обновил свой вопрос